# CakePHP - How to get public path to application root

Tags: cakephp, path

I'm looking for a constant or variable that will provide a public path to my application root.

I have got so far as `FULL_BASE_URL` which gives me `http://www.example.com` but I have the added problem of my application being in a sub directory (e.g. `http://www.example.com/myapp/`).

Is there any way to get the path like `http://www.example.com/myapp/` in my controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$this->Html->url( '/', true );`

In general you should generate all links with that function, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/1448/url

Comment: I forgot to mention this is to get a URL for a redirect in my controller.  I guess it's bad practice to use the HtmlHelper there?

Comment: You don't need the base url for redirects. Just do `$this->redirect( '/controller/action' );`

Comment: Sorry, I made a bit of a mes of this question's details!  It wasn't for a redirect actually, it was for a link in an email template that leads the user back to the site.  I managed to get it working using Html->url() like you said, inside Html->link().  Thanks.

Comment: This is removed in CakePHP 3. Router class should be used instead. See Abba Bryant's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->base;
```

http://api.cakephp.org/class/dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    ...
    $this->redirect( Router::url( "/", true ));
    ...
?>
```

Router is the static class used by the HtmlHelper::link, Controller::redirect etc. the Router::url method takes a string, or array and matches it to a route. Then it returns the url that matched the route info as a string.

If you pass "/" to the Router::url call you get a relative link to the root of your app. If you pass "/" and true to the Router::url call you will prepend the full BASE_URL to the resulting relative path. This should give you what you need. If not, here is the link to the Router documentation. Try experimenting with the second boolean param - it may or may not work as expected depending on what you read / your own testing.

http://api.cakephp.org/class/router#method-Routerurl